# toggle minimize windows only on the active screen only

Tags: 20.04

In ubuntu I am using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to toggle show desktop

But I want this work only the screen where the mouse is there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new shortcut, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Name: Minimize window on mouse cursor

Command:

`xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getmouselocation | sed "s/.*://")`

Note: This doesn't work on 22.04 / Wayland